# Disable double click on arrow key in datatables

Tags: datatables, jquery-plugins

I have a table. If I click 1st time on column header then it should sort the column in provided order. If I am clicking again 2nd or more times on column header then it shouldn't  do anything.

Note: I want to preserve 1st click sorting order.

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: ` orderable: false, target: "_all" ` but it disables sorting although arrow keys are disappeared

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you have already tried. Please also include your DataTables code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply unbind the `click.DT` event handler from the header elements once one of them have been clicked:

```
let table = $('#example').DataTable({})  
table.one('click', 'th', function() {
  $('#example th').each(function() {
    $(this).off("click.DT")
  })  
})
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/u735ca80/**